# Upstart sub-command tab completion with zsh

Tags: command-line, upstart, zsh, auto-completion

I've just recently switched to ZShell, and am loving it so far. One issue I'm having however is that my init.d or upstart scripts used to have tab completion for their subcommands, but now it doesn't.

The most common commands like `start`, `stop`, `status` complete fine, but custom sub commands specific to that script aren't being picked up in zsh tab completion, where they were in BASH.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the copyright is on this hence I'm linking but there's a completion for `initctl`, `start`, `stop`, `restart`, `reload` and `status` [available on the zsh mailing list](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2011/msg00806.html).

Save that as something like `/usr/share/zsh/site-functions/_initctrl`.